# Rename and Relocate Hundreds of Image Files in R

Tags: r, loops, rename

I have hundreds of images in a directory (on MAC) that I want to rename and relocate.

Here is the file naming pattern I am working with

```
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos001_S001_z01.tif
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos001_S001_z02.tif
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos001_S001_z03.tif
...
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos002_S001_z01.tif
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos002_S001_z02.tif
131110 His-RFP female soft wpp 488 sens 546 His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos002_S001_z03.tif
...
```

Notice the PosXXX and zXX are changing in the file names.

This is what I would like to with these files in no particular order:

1)Rename all the files to the following format-

```
    BF_Position001_time101.tif
    BF_Position001_time102.tif
    BF_Position001_time103.tif
...
    BF_Position002_time101.tif
    BF_Position002_time102.tif
    BF_Position002_time103.tif
...
```

PosXXX -> PositionXXX and the zXX -> time1XX

2)Create a directory for each position in the original directory

3)Put the corresponding renamed files in the correct newly created directory.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Does it have to be R or python/bash OK?

Comment: @beroe if I can do it in X11 terminal, which is what I think you mean by bash, that would be great. I would still like to know how to do it in R if it is straight forward from someone else. Thanks

Comment: Looks like Aaron has you covered...

Comment: @beroe maybe not, see comment below :)

Comment: Uh oh. It is always nerve-wracking to test file-mover scripts. Hope you tested it on a backup. Btw, do your file names have all the space-separated text at left as part of the name? (Female, etc)

Comment: I definitely tested on a backup! Yes, file names are as is, spaces and all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f <- list.files(pattern="His-RFP_Mark_and_Find_001_Pos..._S001_z..\\.tif")
pos <- substring(f, 75, 76)
zzz <- substring(f, 84, 85)
f2 <- file.path(paste0("Position", pos), paste0("BF_Position", pos, "_time1", zzz, ".tif"))

lapply(paste0("Position", unique(pos)), dir.create)
file.rename(f, f2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing - What I get if I leave this code and run, all .tif files disappear from directory. New folder called "Positionp 4" is created in original directory, which contains one tif file named "BF_Positionp 4_time1 5.tif"...

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what your filenames were; I thought they just looked like the "pattern" in my code but apparently everything up to that in your post was part of the filename too.  If the position and time elements are always in the same location in the filename, all you need to do is to rework the `substring` commands to choose the proper position.  To check what it will do, inspect `f` (the old names) and `f2` (the new names) before running the last line.

Comment: And I see that it looks like you figured it out already and suggested an edit.  Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for what it is worth, here is how I would do it in python...

To use this, save the file as `renamer.py` (or something). For simplicity, just put it in your images folder, I guess. Then in the terminal window, `cd` to that directory, type `chmod +x renamer.py`. Then type `./renamer.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import os
import glob

pattern = r'.*_Pos(\d+)_S\d+_z(\d+)\.tif'

Flist = glob.glob('*.tif')
for f in Flist:
    search=re.search(pattern,f)
    if search:
        P,T = search.groups()
        FolderName = "Position"+P
        FileName = "BF_Position{}_time1{}.tif".format(P,T)

        try:
            os.renames(f,os.path.join(FolderName,FileName))
        except OSError:
            print f
            print os.path.join(FolderName,FileName)
```